# json array for one to many relations improvements

Tags: php, rest, api

I've a database with three tables:

```
Lemma          LemmaScrittura        LemmaSignificato
-------------  -----------------    ------------------
|id         |  | id             |   | id             |
|category.  |  | writing_1      |   | meaning_ITA    |
|frequency  |  | writing_2      |   | meaning_EN     |
|antonym.   |  | id_Headword(FK)|   | id_Headword(FK)|
-------------  ------------------   ------------------
```

Relations:
1 Lemma -> Many LemmaScrittura
1 Lemma -> Many LemmaSignificato

I'm trying to represent these table in JSON to send these informations to my iOS App; but I've a timing problem.

API
This is the code I use to make API:

read.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include_once("../objects/lemma.php");
include_once("../objects/lemmaScrittura.php");
include_once("../config/database.php");

$lemmaObj = new Lemma();
$stmt = $lemmaObj->read();
$num = $stmt->num_rows;

$scritturaObj = new LemmaScrittura();

if($num > 0){
    $lemmaArr = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){
        extract($row);

        $lemma=array(
            "ambitoUso"         =>  $ambito_Uso,
            "catGramm"          =>  $cat_Gramm,
            "confrontaCon"      =>  $confrontaCon,
            "contrario"         =>  $contrario,
            "frequenza"         =>  $frequenza,
            "kanjiRef"          =>  $kanji_ref,
            "noKanjiLemmaID"    =>  $no_Kanji_Lemma_ID,
            "subCatGramm"       =>  $sub_cat_Gramm,
            "xRef"              =>  $x_ref
        );
        array_push($lemmaArr, $lemma);
    }
        // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);

    // show products data in json format
    echo json_encode($lemmaArr);

}else{
    // set response code - 404 Not found
    http_response_code(404);

    // tell the user no products found
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No headwords found.")
    );
}

?>
```

database.php file is the file to create connection to the DB.

To try the api I use Postman and when I call this API, the request lasts 80-90ms. but if add the second table all change.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include_once("../objects/lemma.php");
include_once("../objects/lemmaScrittura.php");
include_once("../config/database.php");

$lemmaObj = new Lemma();
$stmt = $lemmaObj->read();
$num = $stmt->num_rows;

$scritturaObj = new LemmaScrittura();

if($num > 0){
    $lemmaArr = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){
        extract($row);

        $lemma=array(
            "ambitoUso"         =>  $ambito_Uso,
            "catGramm"          =>  $cat_Gramm,
            "confrontaCon"      =>  $confrontaCon,
            "contrario"         =>  $contrario,
            "frequenza"         =>  $frequenza,
            "kanjiRef"          =>  $kanji_ref,
            "noKanjiLemmaID"    =>  $no_Kanji_Lemma_ID,
            "subCatGramm"       =>  $sub_cat_Gramm,
            "xRef"              =>  $x_ref
        );
        //Thi is the second Table in which I pass the id of Lemma to get the row of LemmaScrittura that has id_Lemma == ID.
        $stmtScrittura = $scritturaObj->read($id);
        $scritturaNum = $stmtScrittura->num_rows;
        if($scritturaNum > 0){
            $scrittureArr = array();
            while($rowScritture = mysqli_fetch_array($stmtScrittura)){
                extract($rowScritture);
                $scrittura = array(
                    "lemmaKanji"    =>  $lemma_Kanji,
                    "lemmaKana"     =>  $lemma_Kana,
                    "lemmaRomaji"   =>  $lemma_Romaji,
                    "lemmaRomaji_1" =>  $lemma_Romaji_1,
                    "lemmaVideo"    =>  $lemma_Video
                );
                array_push($scrittureArr, $scrittura);
            }
            $lemma["scrittura"] = $scrittureArr;
        }


        array_push($lemmaArr, $lemma);
    }
        // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);

    // show products data in json format
    echo json_encode($lemmaArr);

}else{
    // set response code - 404 Not found
    http_response_code(404);

    // tell the user no products found
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No headwords found.")
    );
}

?>
```

If I call this API in which get the row of the second table, the request lasts 45-50 seconds. obviously If I add also third table the duration increase.

Lemma contains +7300 rows and LemmaScrittura contains +7600 rows
My questions are these:

1)Is it normal?
2)How can I improve the API to make the request more fast?
3)I'm in localhost, is different if I was on real server? Could be It more fast?

Thank you very much.

p.s. If you need more information, ask.

Comment: 45-50 Seconds? I have table with more than 5M records and it takes only few seconds for normal query... its not normal... do you have indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make too many database requests !
Make a view or do a select query composed with join query using index from other tables « id_Headword » (or another). Like :

```
SELECT L.*, LS.writing_1 AS ls_writing_1, LS.writing_2 AS ls_writing_2, 
LSG.meaning_ITA AS lsg_meaning_ITA, LSG.meaning_EN AS lsg_meaning_EN 
FROM Lemma AS L 
INNER JOIN LemmaScrittura AS LS
ON(L.id = LS.id_Headword)
INNER JOIN LemmaSignificato AS LSG
ON (L.id = LSG.id_Headword)
```

You can rename column of other data table with « as ». Then you have an organized code and results.

If you want to have all the lines in one, do like this (first value; second value ; third value ; etc.):

```
SELECT L.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LS.writing_1 SEPARATOR ";") AS ls_writing_1,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LS.writing_2 SEPARATOR ";") AS ls_writing_2,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LSG.meaning_ITA SEPARATOR ";") AS lsg_meaning_ITA,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LSG.meaning_EN SEPARATOR ";") AS lsg_meaning_EN
FROM Lemma AS L 
LEFT JOIN LemmaScrittura AS LS
ON(L.id = LS.id_Headword)LEFT JOIN LemmaSignificato AS LSG
ON (L.id = LSG.id_Headword)
```

and afterwards in PHP you recover all easily and you only have to cross the data between them. (first line ; second line; etc.)

**To reduce the speed, you can save all the data in a "json" file. and send the file data directly to your API. Then, if there are any changes, you will update the file (with a button, a cron, etc.).**

The difference that can slow down between a server and a localhost is the bandwidth as well as the number of requests by users and waiting for the response from the server. So locally, it's much faster.

Good luck